# Should VVT Solenoids be replaced in pairs?

Tags: replacements, solenoid

While looking at a Dorman VVT solenoid for my 2011 Skoda Superb 1.8 TSI rockauto throws up this message:

> There are typically 2 VVT Solenoids/Actuators per vehicle (one in the left bank, one in the right bank). When one fails, the other is usually not far behind. Manufacturers recommend replacing these in pairs.

Is this just marketing or is it really common for both the intake and exhaust solenoids to crap out in a relatively short amount of time one from the other?

Comment: No empirical evidence, so will leave this as a comment ... Just like with other things which come in pairs, like brake calipers, It only makes sense to change out both of them. Both actuators are going to have approximately the same amount of wear on them. If one has gone out, it makes sense to me the other isn't far behind. The other part of the equation is, how much time is it going to take you to do the exact same job a second time when the 2nd one finally quits? What is your time worth? Doing it while its all apart makes sense. Maybe they aren't hard to get at? Dunno ... just my 2 cents.

Comment: You might consult a copy of the service manual but the idea does make sense.  Whatever processes caused the first one to fail are almost certainly at work on the other one.  If it were me, I'd change them both unless I knew that the first failure was due to some unusual event that is not impacting the other one.